# Access denied on the index.jsp due to spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

This issue is related to spring security. Whenever I run my application on tomcat by default index.jsp opens but now i am getting access denied on this page.

From index.jsp i am redirecting the page to login.jsp, but since I am getting access denied on this page, redirection is not happening. What i meant to say is if hit: "localhost:8080/abc" I am getting access denied but if I hit "localhost:8080/abc/login" the page opens. (just to be clear, abc is the application context)

I am pretty much sure i have messed up somewhere in the spring security config, because it was working fine before.

Below are my files:

**This is my spring-security.xml**

```
<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
<!--
Add white listed urls here.
Please note that the filter chain will not be applied and the security context not populated.
Use for static resource mostly
-->
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/login" security="none" />
<http pattern="/login1" security="none" />
<http pattern="/googleLogin" security="none" />

<!-- Add protected resource here -->
<http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="forbiddenEntryPoint">
    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="oauth2PreAuthFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/menu" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/request/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/device/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider  ref="AuthenticationService" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="forbiddenEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/>

<beans:bean id="AuthenticationService" class="com.hitesh.security.AuthenticateUserService"/>

<beans:bean id="oauth2PreAuthFilter" class="com.hitesh.security.OAuth2PreAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" class="com.hitesh.security.Oauth2PreAuthenticatedUserService"/>
```

**This is my web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">

<display-name>Inventory Project</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/abc/application.xml,
                 classpath:/abc/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am stuck on this for quite a time, any help will be really appreciated.

**Update:** On application startup, my code is going into the oauth2PreAuthFilter. For index.jsp, it shouldn't run this filter. Is there a way to avoid this, i have tried

```
    <http pattern="/index" security="none" />
```

but this didn't helped.

Comment: So `<http pattern="/index.jsp" security="none" />` did not solve the problem?

Comment: The redirect url should be in your security configuration, not in index.jsp. Is it?

Comment: @jny, I don't understand where in security conf, can you please explain. Although redirection is not a requirement, if i could open the login page directly, that will do. Thanks

Comment: Something along those lines: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.x/guides/form.html

Comment: @jny, this is annotation based but i am using xml for security conf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the fix:

```
   <http auto-config="true" pattern="/index.jsp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (use your values):

```
<http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="forbiddenEntryPoint">
    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="oauth2PreAuthFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/menu" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/request/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/device/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')" />    
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <form-login login-page='/login.htm' default-target-url="/home.htm"/>

</http>
```

Comment: nope, didn't worked. Actually there's no login form. On my login.jsp I have a link for "signin with google account". "Signin with google" is working fine, it's just that i am not able to land on my custom page on application startup. I am getting access denied and as i said earlier, if i manually hit "localhost:8080/abc/login" page opens and then i can continue with the flow